# how to get an pop up when a button is clicked in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I a trying to get a pop up using angualrjs.I have the tried it but unable to get a pop up..The below is  my source code .

```
//HTML file

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src=angularfiles/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.5.1/js/ngDialog.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.5.1/css/ngDialog.css"></script>
<script src="jsfiles/console.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="controller" >
    <div class="container-fluid col-lg-2"  style="background-color:#848482;padding-top:25px;height:657px">


                <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: black;"  ng-click="">Controlls</button> -->
                <h4>Controlls:</h4>


                 <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-dialog="firstDialogId"
        ng-dialog-controller="InsideCtrl"
        ng-dialog-data="{{jsonData}}"
        ng-dialog-class="ngdialog-theme-default"
        ng-dialog-show-close="false">Open via directive</button>

    </div>


</body>
</html>

//js file

var app=angular.module("myapp",['ngDialog']);
myapp.controller("controller",["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.clickme=function(){
        console.log("hi");
        ngDialog.open({
            template: 'externalTemplate.html',
            controller: 'SomeController'
        });
    };
}]);
```

Here the click event is not getting triggerd when i click on the button..Here i have also used bootstrap.Can any one please solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all Few mistakes which I wanna point you here.

1. Use link tag to add external css files.
2. You have created myapp angular module and it's reference variable is `var app=angular.module("myapp",['ngDialog']);` but when registering controller you have used  `myapp.controller("controller",["$scope",function($scope){` **myapp** which is not correct.
3. Here you are trying to open ngDialog on button click but you have not specified `ng-click`  attribute in html template.
4. If I consider you are trying to implement ngDialog with directive then first go through the documentation.
5. Give proper path of ngDialog template. Here you have not added template.
6. while configuring module `['ngDialog']` this means you can use this module in app but if you want the reference of this module then you need to inject that in your controller. it is called dependency injection Which is missing here.
7. You have mentioned here two controllers '**SomeController**'and '**InsideCtrl**' but Did these controllers are registered in myapp module?
8. Go for any one approach either via directive or via controller.Don't use both at the same time.

For your better understanding I have created this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bWLIFZOEbE8bxQWGRGs2?p=preview) for you. Go through it and let me know if you have any confusion in understanding.

Comment: Can i have an simple example for this concept.I have searched many websites ..Those all are not helping me to understand it.Can anyone give me a  simple example.

Comment: @Vindya Veer Check out my edited answer I have given demo for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ng-click="clickme"` attribute in your `button` control.

Comment: Eventhough its not triggering the click event